# custom font not displaying on some simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have tried deleted font from the xcode project and and copied again by dragging, but still custom font named "Helvetica-Neue-LT-Com-75-Bold-Outline.ttf" is **not working on iphone 4 and 5c simulator but working in 5s simulator**.

To set the font name to UILabel, I am using the name from fontbook app.

Comment: Have you ever tried clean project and rebuild it?

Comment: yes I tried cleaning project also uninstalled application from simulator

Comment: Select Front -> and select your target from File Incpector, it's worked for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Delete application from simulator
2. Clean (by hitting "CMD + K" in Xcode)
3. Run again

Comment: now its working it was by mistake wrong function was called for iphone 4 simulator.

Answer (score 44):

Follow this steps,it's work fine

1.Select the project

2.Select Targets->Build Phases->Copy Bundle Resoures->Click + Button->Add your Custom font

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm !! Thanks.

Comment: THANKKK YOUUU!!

Answer (score 14):

Few things after including the font files in your project:

1. Include them in the **target**
2. Include them as **bundle resources**
3. Include them on your **app's plist**
4. Make sure you're referring to the **correct font name**.

You can log all fonts by putting this on your app delegate's *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions*:

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
{
    NSLog(@"%@", family);

    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
        NSLog(@"  %@", name);
    }
}
```

Details here: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: In my case it is logging "pirulen" my custom font and it is also showing when selecting from interface builder but when I run the app it is not showing and picking up the default font.

Answer (score 9):

My problem was that I had a fonts folder which contained my font files, and I added the file by selecting "Create folder references" instead of "Create groups".

When I did this, my fonts folder was blue (instead of yellow), and only the font folder appeared in bundle resources; the individual font files contained in the folder did not.

When I added the folder by selecting "Create groups" the individual font files were added to bundle resources and the fonts appeared in the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're not loading this custom font in the Launch Screen of the App. You can use images instead.

**Custom fonts are not Loading in the LaunchScreen.storyboard**

Comment: Thanks for this. I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.