# Font works in storyboard but fails to work in iOS simuator (Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I've been working on the launch screen of an app and I ran across a problem. The custom font that I was using (grand hotel) shows up in the storyboard but is replaced by a default font in the simulator. It should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuJzD.png), but instead [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXNfI.png) happens. I've tried everything online: added it to the plist, set the target, put it in Copy Bundle Resources. I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution that solves my problem. Is there any way for me to fix this issue? Could it be because it is a launch screen?

Comment: Looks like your constraints arent working.

Comment: The constraints work for the grand hotel font because the letters are written close to each other.  The letter spacing of the other font is bigger.

Comment: did you drag and drop it in your project.

Comment: Check this post may help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168344/xcode-8-custom-font-doesnt-show-up-in-interface-builder/40170579#40170579

Comment: Are you setting this font in storyboard?

Comment: yes I am. Its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps.

(1) Remove your **custom fonts**.

(2) Re-add your font like, Right click on your project **-->** add files **-->** select your custom font. (Make sure option **copy items if needed** is checked).

(3) Clean(**⌘+shift+K**)  + Build(**⌘+shift+B**) your project.

To check if the custom fonts are availabel on runtime add this code:

```
print(UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "Your_Custom_font_name")) // if it returns empty array it means fonts are not available on runtime and it is not added correctly.
```

Comment: I tried this a few times but my issue still isn't resolved

Answer (score 0):

Please check this... may any step you miss
http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: I already checked it out and did everything but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @huvarda how did you end up solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you somewhere set the font programmatically by name?
I figured out, that the name of a certain font is not necessarily the name, which is shown in Xcode. You can check out the real font names in Xcode by putting the following somewhere in your code:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames {
    print("\(family)")
    for names: String in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: family)
    {
        print("== \(names)")
    }
}
```

Comment: he said it "shows up in the storyboard" but not in simulator .

Comment: what doesn't mean, that he isn't somewhere setting/overwriting the font programmatically by a "name", that is shown in storyboard, but slightly differs from the real name.