# Custom font not displayed on Device or simulator Xcode 9.2

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, custom-font

I have problem with custom fonts SFUIDisplay and Montserrat. 
I have done exactly what you should do:

1.Added Font to Info.plist

2.Added Font to Copy Bundle Resources section in Build Phases.

What I have exact problem is set font gives proper output in storyboard but when I run project, custom font "size" will not reflect on simulator nor on device.What is the problem I did not able to find I had face such issue first time.Please suggest what was I  doing wrong.

Guys now I get actual issue is Font size is not displayed properly even I set system font with size 50, simulator display random size.

Comment: What name you are using in your code to apply fonts?

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal I set font through storyboard and not programmatically as it will increase my efforts and time.

Comment: For reference - can go through this link: https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal Thank you for link, I had already performed all 5 steps correctly although my simulator not display correct font don't know what is issue!!!!!!!

Comment: Below link might be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/40170579

Comment: Hey Guys thank you for your kind help I tried everything you suggest but let I elaborate my issue again that is whatever custom font type I was trying to set will easily displayed on storyboard(any font changes also reflect easily on storyboard) but when I hit run command and run on any ipad devices(my app is for Ipad devices only) It will not showing font I set

Comment: @Drashti Hi! did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @zo_chu Yes, I resolved it. There was one common function file where exact same **setfont** method created which override my all custom fonts into a native font.