# Xcode: customize font display wrong style in Xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I added some customize font into my project and want to use it in the storyboard.

The font names are:

```
Frutiger 45 Light.ttf
Frutiger 55 Roman Bold.ttf
Frutiger 55 Roman.ttf
```

Then I want to use it in storyborad by selecting an `UILabel` and set the font.

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the images, the name **Family** is **Frutiger**, but the **Style** is all **Regular**.

Is the font file name problem? Tried "`Frutiger_55_Roman.ttf`" and "`Frutiger-55-Roman.ttf`" way, not working so far.

Thanks!

Comment: it's Xcode bug. just close project and quit xcode then open again. it will show as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding my font folder into `Font Book` in my mac.

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/48927714/291240