# Swift: Custom font not showing up in simulator

Tags: ios, swift

The regular font seems to work, but the all the others (italic, bold, etc.) don't seem to show up on the simulator. Only the storyboard. I added everything to Info.plist and included the files in a custom folder. i don't know what i could have missed! Why is it so hard to add a custom font to swift?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this ?? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636196/opensans-font-not-working-in-ios-simulator

Comment: This example uses objective-C. I'm using swift and haven't put anything in code. I simply added the fonts to info.plist with my folder of custom fonts. For some reason only regular works. I'm perplexed as to why. NOTE: i'm using the inspector only, no code

Comment: Check **Targets** > **Build Phases** > **Copy Resources** . There must be your fonts available. I checked this font in dummy , its working fine in simulator.

Comment: Hmm.. it only works on the storyboard, NOT on the simulator. i have no idea why

Comment: Dahiya, I have the folder containing all the fonts here

Comment: @Bieksa make sure your fonts folder added the file by selecting "Create groups" instead of "Create folder references"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071063/8918347

Comment: @dahiya_boy I put the individual font .ttl files in target and it seemed to work.

Comment: @GovindKumawat that didn't seem to work for me! The only way I could get it to work is to add each .ttl individually in targets. I wonder if there's a simpler way to do this!

Comment: @dahiya_boy, that worked - thanks! Strangely, the first two custom fonts I added and registered via "Targets/Info/Fonts provided by application", were included automatically. One I added later required this extra step - anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Use this function in appDelegate to track font names which you use.

```
func printFonts() {
        let fontFamilyNames = UIFont.familyNames
        for familyName in fontFamilyNames {
            print("------------------------------")
            print("Font Family Name = [\(familyName)]")
            let names = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: familyName)
            print("Font Names = [\(names)]")
        }
    }
```

Call From `didFinishLaunching` in `appDelegate`